# Lodash _.remove() throws: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) and tried the following [remove method](https://lodash.com/docs#remove):

```
_.remove(specFilterBoxItems, function (item) { return item.specId == specId });
```

This throws Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'. Looking at the _ object I see the other Lodash methods but no remove method - see screenshot below:

[image]

I also created the following plucker which does not seem to work either - After should list "Joe": http://plnkr.co/edit/FUftyE3Z2cbDCFJ8tasn

Where is the method or what am I missing?

Comment: see your console. use another cdn link like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js

Comment: @Hacketo that seems to fix it. The link I used is the one provided on lodash.com. Must be a corrupt version?

Comment: it's github raw, the file is sended with a mime type 'text/plain', raw.github should be not used as a cdn.